# Delegating a portable library's functionality to the user interface

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, portability, portable-executable

I'm writing a library in C# that I plan to use in a cross platform application. My goal is to have the core functionality completely separated from the platform-specific apps. This creates a problem for me though.

The main core functionality is done using a Client object. When the client is initialized it loads data from a database, but when the app is first run, there is obviously no user profile created yet, so I need a way to call and await a function inside of the UI project that prompts the user for the needed information. The Client object doesn't have any idea what functionality the UI projects implement though. So my question is, how can I create some sort of generic delegation that will invoke a "Create Profile" screen without knowing anything about the app that is calling it? I've thought of using events, but it would be nice to have the functionality called on the Client's construction/initialization.

If it adds any clarity, I am using Xamarin to create the Android/iOS UIs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the various MVVM frameworks such as MvvmCross. These will do what you need. From a cross platform view model you can navigate to a user profile view model if there isn't a profile yet, and this will show the platform specific screen.